# Generate list of random values and also get a new generator

Tags: haskell, random

I'm using `System.Random` and the `Random` typeclass in my application to generate random numbers.  However I'd like to generate a list of random Floats of arbitrary length with a function like `randoms :: StdGen -> Int -> ([Float], StdGen)`

Without the constraint of getting a new generator, I could easily write
`randoms gen n = (take n $ randoms gen) :: [Float]`

However this leaves me with the same random generator I started with, which means if I were to run this function twice in a row I'd get the same list unless I went and used the generator elsewhere to get a new one.

How can I generate an infinite (or arbitrary length) list of random values while also "refreshing" my random generator.

Comment: Another option is to [`split`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/latest/doc/html/System-Random.html#v:split) the generator in two. Then you can use one of the resulting generators to call `randoms` and continue with the other one. This also works with infinite lists.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, let's look at the function you do have:

```
random :: StdGen -> (Float, StdGen)  -- From System.Random
```

We can wrap this in the `State` monad to get a stateful computation:

```
state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> State s a  -- From Control.Monad.Trans.State

random' :: State StdGen Float
random' = state random
```

Now, we can generate a bunch of floats just using `replicateM`:

```
replicateM :: (Monad m) => Int -> m a -> m [a]  -- From Control.Monad

randoms' :: Int -> State StdGen [Float]
randoms' n = replicateM n random'
```

Finally, we unwrap the `State` to get back the explicit generator passing:

```
randoms :: Int -> StdGen -> ([Float], StdGen)
randoms n = runState (randoms' n)
```

If you combine all of these into one function definition you get:

```
randoms :: Int -> StdGen -> ([Float], StdGen)
randoms n = runState (replicateM n (state random))
```

In other words, we can describe the process as:

- wrap `random` in the `State` monad
- replicate it `n` times
- unwrap it

This is why monads are such an important concept.  Things that can seem tricky at first tend to be simple computations when viewed through the lens of the monad interface.

Answer (score 5):

Gabriel's answer is correct and this is pretty much how the MonadRandom package is implemented (A state Monad parameterised with a random generator).

It saves you defining it every time, and it comes with a Monad transformer too, so you can transform any other Monad into one that can also produce random values.

Your example could be easily implemented as:

```
(runRand $ take n `fmap` getRandoms) :: RandomGen g => g -> ([Int], g)
```

StdGen happens to be an instance of of RandomGen, so you can simply plug it in and go!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative without `State` or `split`, using `mapAccumL` from `Data.List` (and `swap` from `Data.Tuple`):

```
nRandoms n gen =  mapAccumL(\g _ -> swap $ random g) gen [1..n]
```

though I have to say I don't have a convincing argument for why this should be better in any way.

Comment: Is `swap` in standard libraries?

Comment: @BenMillwood `Data.Tuple`. Was recently added, I don't remember how recently exactly. Looked: made its first appearance in ghc-7.0.*. So not extremely recent.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function whose type matches the one you say you’d like to have, albeit more generally.

```
import System.Random

randoms' :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => g -> Int -> ([a], g)
randoms' g n =
  let (g1, g2) = split g
  in (take n $ randoms g1, g2)
```

Even though it uses [`split`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/1.0.1.1/doc/html/System-Random.html#v:split)

> `split :: g -> (g, g)`
>
> The `split` operation allows one to obtain two distinct random number generators. This is very useful in functional programs (for example, when passing a random number generator down to recursive calls), but very little work has been done on statistically robust implementations of `split` …

it still doesn’t do what you want. (I use `Bool` in the examples below for easier visual comparison.)

```
ghci> g <- getStdGen
ghci> randoms' g 5 :: ([Bool], StdGen)
([False,False,False,True,False],1648254783 2147483398)
ghci> randoms' g 5 :: ([Bool], StdGen)
([False,False,False,True,False],1648254783 2147483398)
```

Note that the random arrays are the same.

Although the function goes to the trouble of splitting the generator, we promptly discard it. Instead, make use of `g2` by threading it to the subsequent call as in

```
ghci> let (a1,g2) = randoms' g 5 :: ([Bool], StdGen)
ghci> let (a2,_) = randoms' g2 5 :: ([Bool], StdGen)
ghci> (a1,a2)
([False,False,False,True,False],[True,True,True,False,True]
```

If your code is running in the `IO` monad, you can use [`setStdGen`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/1.0.1.1/doc/html/System-Random.html#v:setStdGen) to replace the global random number generator at the end, as in

```
myAction :: Int -> IO ([Float],[Float])
myAction n = do
  g <- getStdGen
  let (f1,g2) = randoms' g n
  let (f2,g3) = randoms' g2 n
  setStdGen g3
  return (f1, f2)
```

Threading state around is awkward and error-prone. Consider using `State` or `ST` if you have lots of repeated boilerplate.